# How is the union used in this OpenCV library?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am busy trying to learn about OpenCV, but there is one part I do not understand. This is probably an easy question to answer, but I am nonetheless stuck and would appreciate your answer. In OpenCV, a matrix is implemented as follows:

```
typedef struct CvMat {
  int type;
  int step;
  int* refcount;
  union {
    uchar* ptr;
    short* s;
    int* i;
    float* fl;
    double* db;
  } data;
  union {
    int rows;
    int height;
  };
  union {
    int cols;
    int width;
  };
} CvMat;
```

As I understand it, a union means that `int rows` and `int height`, for example, share the same memory location. If that is so, I would expect rows and height to always have the same value. That would then mean we could only have square matrices, which I do not think is the case in OpenCV. So how can we have two different values for rows and height even though it's a union? Could someone please enlighten me as to how this structure works?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No it doesn't mean it's a square.  `rows` means "number of rows", which is essentially the same as `height` (they are not necessarily aliases in other contexts, but as far as OpenCV is concerned that is the case).  Similarly, `cols` means "number of columns" and is just an alias for `width`.

Comment: Ahhhhh so it's just used to provide an alias. Great, thank you. I'd never realised that unions could be used like this. If you'd like to post this as the answer, I will accept it -- if not, I'll do it myself!

Comment: The aliases are likely for backward compatibility reasons.  In general it would be bad design to have different names referring to identical things.

Comment: please, use cv::Mat, the c++ api, and leave the deprecated c-stuff in it's well deserved grave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `rows` means "number of rows", which is essentially the same as `height`.  Similarly, `cols` means "number of columns" and is just an alias for `width`. They are not necessarily aliases in other contexts, but as far as OpenCV is concerned they are treated as such.

This is likely for backward compatibility reasons, as [the official website lists only `rows` and `cols`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html).  Furthermore, note that:

> `CvMat` is now obsolete; consider using `Mat` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Makes perfect sense to me. You have a `union` for `rows`/`height` and one for `cols`/`width`. So you can choose if you prefer calling the horizontal dimension a column or the width.
Separate `union`s do not share the same memory, only the "members" inside *one* `union`.